# Why does this JavaScript Promise reject() get processed at the result callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, asynchronous, promise

Here's a subset of lots more code; JavaScript in Node.js. In essence, the equivalent to function `a` calls for some unit testing (in function `b`). On return from `b`, `a` calls for exception testing (in function `c`). `c` calls for synchronous exception testing (in function `d`). Later, `c` will call another function (`e`, say) for asynchronous exception testing (Promise reject() usage). It seems best to use Promises everywhere in Node.js, but even using them doesn't always result in behavior I predict.

```
'use strict';

function d() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('start d   throw test');
    try {
      throw new Error('Error type');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('d catch block   e.message=' + e.message +
        '   rejecting   to c');
      return reject(new Error('d   ' + e.message));
    } // catch
  }) // Promise
}

function c() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('start c');
    d()
    .then( // d then
      function(result) { console.log('c   d result callback'); },
      function(error) {
        console.log('c   d error callback   error.message=' + error.message +
          '   rejecting   to a');
        return reject(new Error('second try'));
      }
    ) // d then
  }) // Promise
}

function b() {
  console.log('start b   resolving   to a');
  return Promise.resolve();
}

function a() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('start a');
    b()
    .then( // b then
      function(result) {
        console.log('a   b result callback   to c');
        c();
      },
      function(error) { 
        console.log('a   b error callback   error.message=' + error.message);
      }
    ) // b then
    .then( // c then
      function(result) { 
        console.log('a   c result callback   ');
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log('a   c error callback   error.message=' + error.message);
      }
    ) // c then
    .catch(
      function(error) {
        console.log('a   final catch   error.message=' + error.message);
      }
    ) // catch
  }) // Promise
}

a();
```

I predicted, for example that every time I issue a Promise reject(), processing would occur in the caller's error callback. (Note that each `reject()` also uses `new Error`.) Hence, I expected this output in console.log.

```
start a
start b   resolving   to a
a   b result callback   to c
start c
start d   throw test
d catch block   e.message=Error type   rejecting   to c
c   d error callback   error.message=d   Error type   rejecting   to a
a   c error callback   error.message=second try
```

Note that when `d` called reject(), I predicted processing would go to the `c` error callback. Similarly, a `c` reject() would go to the `a` error callback. Instead, I'm getting this output:

```
start a
start b   resolving   to a
a   b result callback   to c
start c
start d   throw test
d catch block   e.message=Error type   rejecting   to c
c   d error callback   error.message=d   Error type   rejecting   to a
a   c result callback
```

The `c` reject() seems to be going to the `a` *result* callback.

Function b may be involved; if I write it out of the program, I get the desired processing. That's great for here, but in the larger code, it is no option.

Questions:

1. Why is processing going to the result callback rather than to the error callback?
2. How does function b cause effect so long after it's done?
3. How can I fix this?
4. What pluses and minuses are tied to using `return reject` versus `reject` alone? Most of the time (at least), it seems to work. I haven't caught the shorter form causing problems.

Comment: it must be `return c();`

Comment: A very interesting read: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html You did the *Rookie mistake #5*, you didn't return c(). Also, don't mix things so much, either use error callback or (re)throw errors (throw is much advised), not both, it's confusing.

Comment: @ShanShan: Thanks for motivating me to reread that article. It is among the best of the articles on Promises I've seen. I didn't fully grasp Rookie mistake #5 before (obviously).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

basic issue is, you did `c();` instead of `return c();`, other issues include:

- method `d`, `c` can be simplified, **stop wrapping promises** with `new Promise(...)`
- avoid usage of `.then(success, error)`, most cases, saner to use `then(success).catch(error)`.
- you code can be reduced to below:

  ```
  'use strict';

  function d() {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Error type'));
  }

  function c() {
    console.log('start c');
    return d()
      .then( result => console.log('c   d result callback'))
      .catch( error => {
        console.log('c   d error callback   error.message=' + error.message +
          '   rejecting   to a');
        throw new Error('second try');
      });
  }

  function b() {
    console.log('start b   resolving   to a');
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  function a() {
      console.log('start a');
    return b()
      .then(result => {
        console.log('a   b result callback   to c');
        return c();      
      }).catch(error => console.log('a   b error callback   error.message=' + error.message))
      .then(result => console.log('a   c result callback   '))
      .catch(error => console.log('a   final catch   error.message=' + error.message));
  }

  a();
  ```

Comment: Thanks lots. You did me two major favors. (1) You identified the "return c()" problem. (2) You demonstrated lots of alternate syntax I hadn't seen. (And it's not lost on me that your code is much shorter than mine and plenty clear!)